# Why do these nullPointerException happen

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have read this post about the null pointer exception but still cannot fix my problem.

This is a playingCard class I wrote for a poker game. I have both the Card class and the Deck class.

```
class Card {

    /* constant suits and ranks */
    static final String[] Suit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    static final String[] Rank = {"", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

    /* Data field of a card: rank and suit */
    private int cardRank;  /* values: 1-13 (see Rank[] above) */
    private int cardSuit;  /* values: 0-3  (see Suit[] above) */

    /* Constructor to create a card */
    /* throw MyPlayingCardException if rank or suit is invalid */
    public Card(int rank, int suit) throws MyPlayingCardException {
        if ((rank < 1) || (rank > 13))
            throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid rank:" + rank);
        else
            cardRank = rank;
        if ((suit < 0) || (suit > 3))
            throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid suit:" + suit);
        else
            cardSuit = suit;
    }

    /* Accessor and toString */
    /* You may impelemnt equals(), but it will not be used */
    public int getRank() {
        return cardRank;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return cardSuit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Rank[cardRank] + " " + Suit[cardSuit];
    }

    /* Few quick tests here */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Card c1 = new Card(1, 3);    // A Spades
            System.out.println(c1);
            c1 = new Card(10, 0);    // 10 Clubs
            System.out.println(c1);
            c1 = new Card(10, 5);        // generate exception here
        } catch (MyPlayingCardException e) {
            System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Decks {

    /* this is used to keep track of original n*52 cards */
    private List<Card> originalDecks;

    /* this starts with n*52 cards deck from original deck   */
    /* it is used to keep track of remaining cards to deal */
    /* see reset(): it resets dealDecks to a full deck      */
    private List<Card> dealDecks;

    /* number of decks in this object */
    private int numberDecks;

    /**
     * Constructor: Creates default one deck of 52 playing cards in originalDecks and
     * copy them to dealDecks.
     * initialize numberDecks=n
     * Note: You need to catch MyPlayingCardException from Card constructor
     * Use ArrayList for both originalDecks & dealDecks
     */
    public Decks() {
        // implement this method!

        ArrayList<Card> originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
        ArrayList<Card> dealDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);

        Card card;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {

                try {
                    card = new Card(j, i);

                    if (card != null) {
                        **originalDecks.add(card);**
                    }
                } catch (MyPlayingCardException e) {

                    System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: " + e.getMessage());

                }

            }  //end of 1st for loop
        }      //end of 2nd for loop

        dealDecks.addAll(originalDecks);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor: Creates n decks (52 cards each deck) of playing cards in
     * originalDecks and copy them to dealDecks.
     * initialize numberDecks=n
     * Note: You need to catch MyPlayingCardException from Card constructor
     * Use ArrayList for both originalDecks & dealDecks
     */
    public Decks(int n) {
        int numberDecks = n;
        Card card;

        for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j <= 13; j++) {

                    try {
                        card = new Card(j, i);
                        if (card != null) {
                            **originalDecks.add(card);**
                        }
                    } catch (MyPlayingCardException e) {
                        System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        dealDecks.addAll(originalDecks);
    }
}
```

The null pointer exception happens on the line in strong which is card = new Card(j, i). I read this post and think my problem is the "card=null" case, so I added "if(card != null)", but it didn't fix the problem. What went wrong here?

Comment: FYI, in code Markdown you cannot apply additional Markdown (like the **strong** you tried to apply).

Answer (score 1):

You have two `Decks` constructors, which have two different problems:

#### The `Decks()` constructor (no arguments):

This line in your `Deck()` constructor creates a **local** variable that shadows (hides) your instance member:

```
ArrayList<Card> originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
```

That means that you never initialize your instance member, and so it keeps its default value (`null`). If you try to do anything with your **instance member** (e.g., outside that constructor), it will fail with an NPE, because you've never assigned anything to your instance member.

The line you've highlighted in that constructor will not throw, because it uses the local variable, not the instance member.

To initialize the instance member rather than declaring and initializing a local variable in the constructor, remove the return type so you're not declaring a variable, you're just assigning to your instance member:

```
originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
```

You have the same problem with `dealDecks`.

#### The `Decks(int)` constructor:

This one's simpler: You never assign to `originalDecks`, and so it keeps its `null` value, and the line you've highlighted throws. If it didn't, it would throw later, on the `dealDecks.add` line, because you've never assigned anything to `dealDecks`, either.

---

*This bit is subjective*

That first issue is one of the reasons I recommend always using `this.` when referring to instance members:

```
this.originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
```

That way A) It's clear you're dealing with an instance member rather than a local variable, and B) So you can't make that mistake (as `ArrayList<Card> this.originalDecks = ...` would be a syntax error). Some IDEs and lint tools even have an option you can enable to make not using `this.` on instance mebers an error or warning.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the problem. I"M trying to create the originalDeck and dealDeck in the constructor, instead of instance variable.

Comment: @LijieZhou: There are actually two problems, depending on which constructor you're talking about. Both need fixing, see above. The fix is the same in both cases: Initialize the instance member, because neither constructor does that.